# Create an expression from existing expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, expression

I need to create a new expression with a different argument based on an existing expression.

I have the following existing expression:
`Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter1`
and I need to create a new expression using the same body, but instead of T parameter I want to replace it with a new U parameter, like this:
`Expression<Func<U, bool>> filter2`

When filter1 is declared, it is a generic expression:

```
ForEntity<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter1) where T: IEntity
```

Which I need to explicitly convert it to

```
ForEntity<IEntity>(Expression<Func<IEntity, bool>> filter2)
```

In order to use it in a collection of filters to send each of them to EF Core like this:

```
context.DbSet.Where(filter2)
```

This is generic made as the main usage of the objects will be like this:

```
someService.ForEntity<MyEntity>((x) =>
               (x.CreatedDate < DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-50)) && (x.SomeProperty == "SomeValue"))
           .ForEntity<MyEntity2>((x) =>
               (x.CreatedDate < DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-40)) && (x.SomeProperty2 == "SomeValue2"))
           .ForEntity<MyEntity3>((x) =>
               (x.CreatedDate < DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-30)) && (x.SomeProperty3 == "SomeValue3"));
```

What I have done so far is trying to recreate and replace the T parameter in this way:

```
ForEntity<TEntity>(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter) where TEntity : IEntity
{
     ParameterExpression x = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IEntity), "x");
     Expression<Func<IEntity, bool>> newFilter = Expression.Lambda<Func<IEntity, bool>>(filter.Body, x);

     simpleEntities.Add(new SimpleEntity(typeof(TEntity), newFilter));
}
```

But when executing the query at runtime, it throws the following error:

```
The LINQ expression 'DbSet<MyEntity>
    .Where(i => x.CreatedDate < DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-50) && x.SomeProperty== "SomeProperty")' could not be translated
```

I have no idea where the "i" in this translated expression comes from honestly.

Comment: You're trying to rebuild LINQ. Why? `ForEntity` seems to do what `Where` does.  `In order to use it in a collection of filters to send each of them to EF Core like this:` you don't need to do anything special, for that. `query=query.Where(someExpression)` will create a new query with an additional expression and replace the old one

Comment: Not quite, I am trying to build a generic service that can be used in any app to delete any entity based on a filter for that specific entity not the base IEntity, at a specific interval of time. Obviously I have to work with generics to support any entity type, so even the context is the generic DbContext that will be cast at runtime to a specific type. As in this service I do not have the exact entity type, this is why I am going that road.

Comment: You are describing EF Core and LINQ themselves. A DbSet is generic. A DbContext is generic. Where is generic. `Where` would have no problem handling `Where(x=>x.CreatedDate < DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-50))` because it would recognize the external data (the date calculated by DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-50)) and use it as a parameter value. EF Core doesn't use any special magic though. It recognizes that the date expression does *not* use the entity as a parameter. Your own code hides that.

Comment: The [LinqKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) library was created to solve the original problem you encountered: creating complex EF LINQ queries dynamically fails because `Expression<Func<T,bool>>` loses important information. It solves that with a bit of rewriting to ensure the final query contains the proper information. And no, I don't quite understand how all that works. I just know that [PredicateBuilder](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit#using-predicatebuilder) does work and makes chaining  complex `And` and `Or` conditions very easy

Comment: Totally agree however the problem is in transmitting the correct concrete data back to the generic use when doing the actual `SELECT`. It's down the road of the conversions where data is lost or not able to being converter. I will give the library a try, it may just do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

You can use EF Core's `ReplacingExpressionVisitor` for such task:

```cs
ForEntity<TEntity>(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter) where TEntity : IEntity
{
     ParameterExpression x = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IEntity), "x");
     var correctedBody = ReplacingExpressionVisitor.Replace(filter.Parameters[0], x, filter.Body);
     Expression<Func<IEntity, bool>> newFilter = Expression.Lambda<Func<IEntity, bool>>(correctedBody, x);

     simpleEntities.Add(new SimpleEntity(typeof(TEntity), newFilter));
}
```

Comment: Hi Danyliv, this was perfect, however it throws exception at runtime when trying to replate the concrete implementation. Even though the concrete implementation is of type IEntity, it throws the error : `ParameterExpression of type 'MyEntity' cannot be used for delegate parameter of type 'IEntity`

Comment: Missed that part. Will prepare transformation in a hour.